# How to always show end of text in windows form textbox c# (even when not focused)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

**CONTEXT :**

- I'm using visual studio 2017 on a win 10 computer.
- I'm developing a C# windows form app.
- The app saves files to a directory. (Here pictures and
  videos)
- You can select the wanted folder with a button. ([...])
- The selected folder's path then shows in the textbox.
- The textbox is always set to disabled. (I want the user to always go through the `FolderBrowserDialog` to select the desired folder)

**QUESTION :**

I want the textbox to always show the end of my selected folder's text even when not in focus.

[image]

[image]

I'm limited in space and can't stretch the textbox to show all the path.

Here, I would like the textbox to show something like :

`...\morneaulo\Desktop` instead of `C:\Users\morneaulo\Des...`

I would also prefer to keep all the available text in the textbox because I use the textbox.Text property when the files are saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to set it in code behind like so:

```
FileTextBox.SelectionStart = FileTextBox.Text.Length;
FileTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @LoukMo You can also do this in one line: `FileTextBox.Select(FileTextBox.Text.Length, 0)`;

Comment: @LarsTech: +1 for elegance.